# Unit Testing JNI Calls

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I have an Android JNI wrapper for some C++ code. The C++ code has it's own set of unit tests.
I want to write Java unit-tests for the JNI wrapper class.

Is there a way to unit-test the Android JNI `.so` wrapper API from the desktop console e.g. on Windows? Maybe using a desktop Java framework but with all the Android SDK calls?

Answer (score 1):

Since the class that calls into native is just a wrapper class, then you can just unit test the JNI layer. If that is what you want, then it would be a bit hard to unit test your JNI functions directly. However, you can still take the "core" of your JNI function that does all the work and put that in a separate .c file. So basically, you would include your new class in the JNI class and make that class do all the wor. Now, you would have a .c class with a set of methods that can be easily unit tested.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, this can be a good method and is very efficient, but it's important to be aware that different platforms and C libraries behave in subtly different ways - for example subtle errors can be experienced different on a 32-bit Android system than when built for a (typically) 64-bit development host - it won't necessarily catch risky assumptions about implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: As I said in the question the C++ code already has it's own unit-tests, as does a C wrapper for the C++ API.  What I want to UT is the JNI code, which often has platform specific data conversions which cannot really be ported or isolated to native C.